# Derivative of an inverse function - messy

Tags: calculus

The question is given $f(x)=(x+1)^{1/3} +x$.

Find $(f^{-1})'(9).$
I read that as find the derivative of the inverse evaluated at $(9)$.  Find the inverse, take the derivative and evaluate at $(9)$.  But, since the derivative has both x and y, what gets the value of $9$ and what happens to the other variable.  Lost on this.

Finding the inverse of that function was messy. Substitute x for y and y for x and cubing both sides gives:  $f^{-1}(x)=(x^3-1)/(3x^2+3xy-y^{2}+1)$.  Right away this seems odd since it is a function of $x$ AND $y$.

I can now find the derivative of this; however it is a function of both $x$ and $y$.  So, my question is when I evaluate the derivative of $f^{-1}(9)$, would seem like that leaves a variable of y in the equation that does not cancel out.

What am I missing here?  Book answer is $12/13$.

Comment: The answers below are correct, but note that you had a pretty big error in the computation of the inverse. It is a conceptual error, given that you end up with a function of two variables! I think it may be beneficial to review some basic theory about inverse functions :)

Comment: Yes, I completely agree that I should know that I cannot end up with the inverse being a function of 2 variables. I'm going to review in detail the theory behind inverses.

Comment: These problems are almost always asked to be done without a calculator.  If you don't just happen to see visually  that $x=7$ works , you are stuck using rational roots with the constant term being $728$ to solve that cubic equation. Seems computationally to be a poor problem for a timed test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to find $f^{-1}$ ,but it is easy to find $f^{-1}(9)$ 
$$(9,a) \in f^{-1}\Leftrightarrow(a,9)\in f$$ so we can find $a$ then find $f'$ then $\frac{1}{f'}$
$$\sqrt[3]{x+1}+x=9 \to x=7 \\\to 
f'(x)=\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}}+1\underbrace{=}_{x=9}\frac{1}{12}+1=\frac{13}{12} \to (f^{-1})'(9)=\frac{1}{f'(7)}=\frac{12}{13}$$

Comment: all I can say is wow.  I was so stuck on finding the inverse.

Comment: @ser163862:Sometimes its very hard to find $f$ inverse . When $(f^{-1})'(x_0)$ is needed , it is better to do like this .

Answer (score 2):

No need to compute the inverse function.  First note that $f(7) = 9$. Then compute $f'(7)=13/12$. Since $f(7) = 9$, $$(f^{-1})'(9)= \frac{1}{f'(7)}=12/13$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:
$$y=(x+1)^{1/3}+x \Rightarrow x=(y^{-1}+1)^{1/3}+y^{-1}$$
Taking implicit differentiation:
$$1=\frac13(y^{-1}+1)^{-2/3}(y^{-1})'+(y^{-1})' \Rightarrow (y^{-1})'=\frac{1}{1+\frac13(y^{-1}+1)^{-2/3}}$$
From the orignal equation:
$$y=(x+1)^{1/3}+x \Rightarrow 9=(x+1)^{1/3}+x \Rightarrow x=7=y^{-1}(9)$$
Hence:
$$(y^{-1})'(9)=\frac{1}{1+\frac13(7+1)^{-2/3}}=\frac{12}{13}.$$